# BluetoothGattServerCallback does not call onConnectionStateChange

Tags: android, android-studio, bluetooth-lowenergy, gatt

I have an app (Lollipop) that advertises to a Recon JET which will discover it with its own app. They will successfully connect, and I know this because I have a button that calls BluetoothManager.getConnectedDevices(BluetoothProfile.GATT) and returns a MAC address. Although it connects, it won't call the onConnectionStateChange.

Here is how I advertise to the JET:

```
    if(advertiser == null){
        shouldAdvertise = true;
    }

    BluetoothManager bluetoothManager = (BluetoothManager) this.getSystemService(BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);

    //Add advertise settings to the advertisement
    final AdvertiseSettings settings = new AdvertiseSettings.Builder()
            .setAdvertiseMode( AdvertiseSettings.ADVERTISE_MODE_BALANCED )
            .setTxPowerLevel( AdvertiseSettings.ADVERTISE_TX_POWER_HIGH )
            .setConnectable( false )
            .build();

    //Create a ParcelUUID object out of the Service UUID
    ParcelUuid pUuid = new ParcelUuid( ServiceUuid  );

    //Add advertise data to the advertisement
    final AdvertiseData data = new AdvertiseData.Builder()
            .setIncludeDeviceName( true )
            .addServiceUuid( pUuid )
            .addServiceData( pUuid, "Data".getBytes( Charset.forName( "UTF-8" ) ) )
            .build();

    //Create the temperature characteristic that will be on the server
    final BluetoothGattCharacteristic btTemp =
            new BluetoothGattCharacteristic(TempUuid,
                    //Read+write permissions
                    BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PROPERTY_READ | BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PROPERTY_WRITE,
                    BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PERMISSION_READ | BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PERMISSION_WRITE);

    //Create the humidity characteristic that will be on the server
    final BluetoothGattCharacteristic btHum =
            new BluetoothGattCharacteristic(HumUuid,
                    //Read+write permissions
                    BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PROPERTY_READ | BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PROPERTY_WRITE,
                    BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PERMISSION_READ | BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PERMISSION_WRITE);

    //Create the pressure characteristic that will be on the server
    final BluetoothGattCharacteristic btPres =
            new BluetoothGattCharacteristic(PresUuid,
                    //Read+write permissions
                    BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PROPERTY_READ | BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PROPERTY_WRITE,
                    BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PERMISSION_READ | BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PERMISSION_WRITE);

    //Create the adapter from the manager
    BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter = bluetoothManager.getAdapter();
    advertiser = bluetoothAdapter.getBluetoothLeAdvertiser();
    bluetoothAdapter.setName("Data Hub Server");

    /**
     * The callback for the advertisement. Basically will declare if the
     * advertisement succeeded or if it failed.
     */
    final AdvertiseCallback advertisingCallback = new AdvertiseCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onStartSuccess(AdvertiseSettings settingsInEffect) {
            super.onStartSuccess(settingsInEffect);
            Log.d("FATAL","Advertising...");
        }

        @Override
        public void onStartFailure(int errorCode) {
            Log.e( "FATAL", "Advertising onStartFailure: " + errorCode );
            super.onStartFailure(errorCode);
        }
    };

    //Create the server
    BluetoothGattServer server = bluetoothManager.openGattServer(this,mGattCallback);
    Toast.makeText(this, server.toString() , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    //Create the service to hold the characteristics
    BluetoothGattService service =new BluetoothGattService(ServiceUuid,
            BluetoothGattService.SERVICE_TYPE_PRIMARY);

    // Add the characteristics to the service and add the service to
    // the server
    service.addCharacteristic(btTemp);
    service.addCharacteristic(btHum);
    service.addCharacteristic(btPres);
    boolean serviceAdded = server.addService(service);
    Log.d("FATAL","Was the service added? : " + Boolean.toString(serviceAdded));

    //Start advertising
    if(shouldAdvertise) {
        advertiser.startAdvertising(settings, data, advertisingCallback);
        shouldAdvertise = false;
    }
```